# Is it possible to exploit a query via SQL Injection when the input is stripped of all apostrophes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-injection

I have been converting insecure dynamic queries to parameterized queries. I have figured out ways to exploit most of the weaker attempts people have made in an attempt to sanitize their input but I have not figured out how to actually exploit a query that is essentially

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100) = ''';SELECT ''INJECTED''--'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT ''example'' WHERE ''1'' = ''' + REPLACE(@input, '''', '') + ''''
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

or

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100) = ''';SELECT ''INJECTED''--'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT ''example'' WHERE ''1'' = ''' + REPLACE(@input, '''', '''''') + ''''
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

I have seen people online break escaping (in MySQL but never TSQL) but I have not been able to find any way to break stripping single quotes.

I plan on fixing the above instances, too, but I cannot figure out how to demonstrate that they are insecure.

How can you exploit the above queries?

Comment: No that is not effectively safe. You can still send in binary data which will contain no apostrophes but will still wreak havoc. Why not use proper parameterized queries and stop executing strings? There are VERY few times when you really need dynamic sql...and even dynamic sql can be parameterized.

Comment: Doubling quotes is not even close to safe.

Comment: Invaluable reference on dynamic sql in sql server: [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Why spend time and effort pondering these things. The right solution is parameterization. That is 100% effective because it separates *code* from *data*. Even if *we*, random strangers on the internet, tell you that your mad encoding scheme is okay, how will you be *sure*?

Comment: I already said I am fixing these. I am the one that discovered them and demanded that we fix them. For my own knowledge I am curious if there is an easy way around the two methods I posted.

Comment: @Marie - well, the obvious problem with option one is that `'`s could very well be *valid data* and you're wrecking it. I'm not immediately aware of a simple escape from option two. But there is **no** good reason to do either so it seems pointless to ask.

Comment: I ask because I want to know. What more reason does anybody need? Besides that the danger effects the priority which decides when/if I am allowed to fix these issues.

Comment: So, we go back to my previous comment. You're willing to re-prioritise work based on "random strangers on the internet told me it's safe", rather than fixing the problem? That's not a sane process to work with.

Comment: Your reading comprehension needs work. I dont get a say in the matter. If i can prove it can be broken then I can fix it now. If I cannot prove it can be broken they may say we will fix it eventually. I plan to argue for fixing it immediately regardless but it would definitely help my case if somebody answered my question instead of arguing with me about it.

Comment: @Marie [Some good reading on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string).  But more importantly, by stripping out the `'`'s, you're *destroying user data*.  You should *never* be altering a user's input to protect against SQL Injection.  Additionally, yes, it is very possible to do SQLi with your `'` "fix."  Use what's been proven to work, otherwise you're just waiting for someone to be creative and exploit it.  Be *proactive*, **not** *reactive*...

Comment: @Marie ... and we *are* answering your question.  If your management or whoever is pushing back on these changes because "it hasn't happened yet," you need to make them understand that the changes are needed.  The last thing you want is to find out the hard way.  If your company can't understand that risk, maybe you should look for a new company.  Use parameterized sql.  Period.  There is not an alternative.  Everything else is exploitable.

Comment: You're getting your answer, but not in the form you wanted. *Nobody* considers escaping to be "effectively safe". We don't spend lots of time trying to *prove* that it's unsafe. We know that the fundamental flaw that is surfaced by SQL injection is when data is treated (potentially) as code. So we avoid that situation completely and know that we're safe (from SQLi)

Comment: I think what you want is only an answer to your question and not an explanation. In that vein here is my answer to is the original query here safe. NO

Comment: With binary as I mentioned previously. I will update my answer with a working example to show you.

Comment: That would be awesome, thank you

Comment: Take a look at the edits to my original answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can and should still parameterize your dynamic sql to make it truly safe. Your example query could be something like this.

```
declare @z int = 10

EXEC sp_executesql 'SELECT x FROM y WHERE MyColumn = @z', N'@z int', @z
```

Now we have created a parameterized query inside your dynamic sql and passed the parameter to the execution. This is NOT vulnerable to sql injection.

--EDIT--

Since you wanted an answer to the question of if your original query is vulnerable to sql injection I will demonstrate that it is in fact quite open. You are only dealing with single quotes which is truly on the tip of the iceberg when it comes to sql injection. Have you considered what happens if instead of a string they pass in a binary representation of a string?

Let's say your query is receiving a nvarchar(max) as a parameter. In my example I call this @BadCode. Now in my example I am not doing any harm to your system but in the wild this binary could be literally anything.

Here is a simple stored procedure with a pattern very close to what you demonstrated.

```
create procedure InjectionTest
(
    @BadCode nvarchar(max)
) as
    set @BadCode = REPLACE(@BadCode, '''', '')
    EXEC sp_executesql @BadCode

GO
```

Now from the front end I am going to pass in the value 0x730065006C0065006300740020002A002000660072006F006D0020007300790073002E00640061007400610062006100730065007300. Again, this is harmless binary here. If you want to see simply put that inside a convert(varchar(max),...

Here is an example of the above procedure being called. The binary string coming in is what the user would pass in. Notice there are no single quotes in that.

```
declare @Test nvarchar(max) = 0x730065006C0065006300740020002A002000660072006F006D0020007300790073002E00640061007400610062006100730065007300

exec InjectionTest @Test
```

There are plenty of much longer explanations and more trickery but this demonstrates the basics of how this can easily be broken.

Comment: Yes. It should be a cardinal rule to never build up SQL from string concatenation in any system that will be exposed to user input. Always parameterize SQL.  This has the added benefit of not polluting the plan cache, somewhat improving performance.

Comment: I know that and I am already updating all of these. I was just curious if it is easily exploited because I couldnt think of a way. This also doesnt even remotely answer my question.

Comment: Your edit definitely proves the first example. It looks like it covers the second example, too, but I cant figure out how to convert a string to binary that works. running `SELECT convert(binary, '1'';union all select ''test''')` returns `0x31273B756E696F6E20616C6C2073656C6563742027746573742700000000` which comes up as `✱画楮湯愠汬猠汥捥⁴琧獥❴  `. How did you get that binary?

Comment: Use convert(varbinary(max), 'Your String Here')

Comment: Strangely that didnt work for me, even converting the result from @Test gave a slightly different and shorter binary result. Besides that, It looks like the conversion happens immediately as the binary is assigned to @Test which means `REPLACE(@BadCode, '''','')` would still strip any apostrophes and protect against injection.

Comment: Well as I said this is barely the tip of the iceberg of what can happen. Yes this contrived example would actually make that work. Consider if they don't pass in a single quote, it is vulnerable to injection. Consider if instead of select * from sys.databases it was instead ";drop database master;--" No single quotes there and your master database goes bye bye. Up to you if you think you are safe. I am telling you that your code is not safe.

Comment: @Sean I never said I thought I was safe. I said I need to come up with a way to prove that they are not safe so they will let me fix it. Passing in sql directly wont work because everything is concatenated with `'`s wrapping it and any `'` in the term replaced. Use the queries I posted in my question, they are safe from your examples so your examples don't help me at all.

Comment: OK then I give up. I really dislike the approach your code takes because it changes user input. The code presented is highly risky unless you modify the original data by removing all single quotes. I am pretty sure there are some other ways to break this that I can't think of. Given the nature of your question I suspect you actually realize this is dangerous or you wouldn't have asked in the first place. I really don't like systems that change my input because they are not written well enough to handle reasonable data.

Answer (score -1):

As others mentioned, trying to cleanse the input is the most fraught option available.  Best option is to never let the input become executable code...

Here's a safe pattern for VARCHAR(MAX) lists in params. It does require STRING_SPLIT or equivalent function (SQL Server 2016 and higher. Not sure about other SQL flavors)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectSomeListOfIDs (
    @AnyDelimitedIDList VARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN

    --The idea here is to make the list creation flexible and non-brittle for non-technical users and external calls.  Overkill for most scenarios.  Depending on the expected data, some delimiters should definitely be taken out.
    REPLACE @AnyDelimitedIDList = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        @AnyDelimitedIDList
        ,CHAR(09),'|')  --Tab
        ,CHAR(10),'|')  --LF
        ,CHAR(13),'|')  --CR
        ,CHAR(44),'|')  --Comma
        ,CHAR(59),'|')  --SemiColon
        ,CHAR(58),'|')  --Colon
        ,CHAR(46),'|')  --dot
        ,CHAR(34),'|')  --DoubleQuote
        ,CHAR(39),'|')  --SingleQuote
        ,CHAR(32),'|')  --Space

    --this enables the input to never become executable code
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #IDList
    SELECT ID = x.value
    INTO #IDList
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AnyDelimitedIDList,'|') x
    WHERE ISNULL(x.value,'') <> ''

    --Obviates the need for Dynamic SQL 
    SELECT ID
    FROM dbo.MyTable x
    JOIN #IDList  list
        ON x.ID = List.ID --safe from sql injection 

    --Dynamic SQL is no longer needed for the sake of the ID List, but if Dyn is still needed/desired, the list can still be simplified and made safe:
    DECLARE @dummyScalar DATETIME = GETDATE()
    EXEC ('
        SELECT ID
        FROM dbo.MyTable x
        JOIN #IDList  list --safe from sql injection, and a bit simpler
            ON x.ID = List.ID
        WHERE x.date > '''+@dummyScalar+'''
    ')

END
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I was explicitly trying to prove why this is a bad idea to my teams leadership at the time, in order to encourage them to change it. People saying it is bad practice does not convince anybody, so this answer does not answer my question or help my situation